# "expand-text" not supported for children of <xsl:text>

Tags: xslt, saxon, xslt-3.0

I’m using “expand-text” in an XSLT3 stylesheet. The following w3.org note says that "text value templates should apply to text node children of xsl:text if an expand-text='yes' attribute is in scope".

http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-qt-comments/2014Aug/0059.html

This doesn't appear to be working in Saxon-EE 9.5.1.7. For example:

```
<xsl:message expand-text="yes">
    {1+1}
    <xsl:text>{1+1}</xsl:text>
</xsl:message>
```

Outputs:

```
2
{1+1}
```

That is to say, the expression is correctly evaluated outside the `<xsl:text>` but not inside it.

Michael Kay subsequently replied to the above w3.org note with the comment "the changes have been applied" suggesting it is fixed in some release of Saxon. Can anyone confirm? Any hint what release I need to look at?

Thanks,
Josh.

Comment: The spec was changed after 9.5 was released. As a general rule, I don't implement spec changes in a maintenance release, only in major releases (but there are exceptions when the spec change is itself a bug fix, or sometimes if it is particularly urgent). The comment "the changes have been applied" refers to my role as editor of the spec, and means that an agreed change has been applied to the spec; it has nothing to do with the Saxon implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just tested your code with an XSLT 3.0 stylesheet and Saxon 9.6.0.3 EE and it outputs `2` two times. So that version of Saxon implements the change.
And another test with Saxon 9.6 PE also gives the same result.